# Read Meta Tags from a PHP file

Tags: php

I'm trying to load meta tags from a php file that relates to the page that's loading.

The meta code works but only if I add the meta code to each page.

1. I would rather not add the meta code to each page.
2. I want to us an include with this code in it
3. BUT the include isn't getting populated.

Here's the code:

1. **Again this code works if I add it to each page**.
2. **If I remove and add an include with this code** it doesn't populate the metas.

   ```
       <?php include("includes/metatgs.php"); ?> 
       <?php if ($page = basename(__FILE__)); ?>
   <?php { ?>
       <meta charset='<?php echo $meta[$page]['charset']; ?>'>
       <title><?php echo $meta[$page]['title']; ?></title>
       <meta name='description' content='<?php echo $meta[$page]['description'];?>'>
       <meta name='keywords' content='<?php echo $meta[$page]['keywords']; ?>'>
   ```

   metatgs.php : **This is what I'm using to populate the metas.**

   ```
   $meta['index.php']['charset'] = "utf-8";
   $meta['index.php']['title'] = "Home";
   $meta['index.php']['description'] = "The Description";
   $meta['index.php']['keywords'] = "keywords";

   $meta['about.php']['charset'] = "utf-8";
   $meta['about.php']['title'] = "About";
   $meta['about.php']['description'] = "The Description";
   $meta['about.php']['keywords'] = "keywords";
   ```

How can I add this code to an include and populate the metas?

Comment: defining meta for all pages is the hard approach in the dynamic web
you only need to define the current page meta based on db data

Comment: Are you using some template?

Comment: 100% sure the file is being included? Also, have you verified what `$page` holds?

Comment: Yes and if I look at the source the metas are there but not populated.

Comment: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'metainchd.php'</font> <i>(length=7)</i>
</pre>

Comment: Yes if you look the second code post it holds what's posted.  And those metas are populated with that data only if I add the meta code in each page.  It doesn't work when I add it to an include and add that include in the pages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do to get the right meta tags to the right page.

1. Create a folder and name it meta_tags
2. Create php pages in it based on pages you want to use meta tags.example index_meta_tags.php , about_meta_tags.php, contact_meta_tags.php
3. in the page you are in ex. index.php you want to use index_meta_tags.php
   so you can write this code

---

```
$current_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); //get currect page name ex. index.php

if(current_page == "index.php"){<br/>
     include "index_meta_tags.php";<br/>
}else if(current_page == "about.php"){<br/>
     include "about_meta_tags.php";<br/>
}else if(current_page == "contact.php"){<br/>
     include "contact_meta_tags.php";<br/>
}
```

So you will have the right meta tags based on page

Comment: Why would I want to created 10 pages doing what you said?  My idea is one include and one php file with all the data needed?

Answer (score 0):

According to your post and comments, my guess is that `$page` is not what you expect it to be. Since you are not using a function of any kind with the include, variable scope is not an issue. Depending on your `error_reporting()` setting, PHP won't throw an error for an undefined index.

I would recommend modifying your [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) setting and see what the `$page` value is. Then ensure you are actually defining an array for that page withing `$meta`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - I replaced

```
<?php if ($page = basename(__FILE__)); ?>
```

with this

```
<?php if ($page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); ?>
```

I might give Programmatistis credit since he mentioned ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).  But really thinking about it since he wanted to rewrite the world and add 10 more pages rather than my easy solution.